# 'dynamic' enabling and disabling of jquery sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have two divs one called menu and one called dropbox. I can drag images between both the divs. this is until i introduce sortable on the dropbox div. This allows images in the dropbox div to be reorganised within the div. Is there a way to use sortabe when the mouse is within a certain div?

The two divs i have:

```
<div id="menu" class="section"  ondragover="return false">
        <img class="images" ng-repeat="img in HTML" ng-src="{{img}}"/>
    </div>
<div id="dropbox" class="section"  ondragover="return false">
    </div>
```

The jquery I'm trying to use at the moment:

```
$(function() 
          {
            $('#dropbox').mouseover(function (){
                $( "#dropbox" ).sortable();
                $( "#dropbox" ).disableSelection();
            });
            $('#menu').mouseover(function (){
                $( "#dropbox" ).sortable('disable');
                $( "#dropbox" ).disableSelection('disable');
            });

          });
```

My logic is that when the mouse is over the dropbox div enable sortable and when the mouse is over the menu div disable the sort to allow the images to be dragged in.
I just want to know if this is possible as im not sure

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. What problem is this trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl I inject images into the dropbox div. I have them so they can be sorted while within the dropbox div. I want to be able to drag them back out of the dropbox div but I cant because sortable is active and this stops me dragging them back out

Comment: Sortable can be also dropped elsewhere see: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: @charlietfl thats exactly what i was looking for! can you make this an answer please so i can accept and upvote? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to disable `sortable` to make the elements droppable elsewhere.

Just add the `connectWith` option as seen in the [connected lists demo](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) in jQuery UI docs